# Reset message visibility Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an azure storage Queue with many messages, that were checked out (getQueueMessages) with a very long visibility timeout (>72hrs, setVisibilityTimeoutInSeconds). The dequeue process crashed, leaving of millions of messages stuck in the queue, we have to wait now a long time until they expire and become visible in the queue again.

Is there a way to reset the visibility timeout for all messages in the queue, that is, to make all invisible messages visible again, without having the pop receipt/id for each message?

Comment: Are you using the Java API? I'm guessing so by the method names.

Comment: yes, I am using the Java API and I couldnt find any method, I was hoping there was a reset button, or maybe some HTTP call using the REST api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Once the messages are dequeued they are not visible to any other callers. If you have message contents, you could just clear the queue and then put these messages again.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, When the queue items are grabbed with a visibility time-out, there is no way to see them (apart from the original process which grabbed it) even using the clients like Azure Storage Explorer or Cerebrata Cloud Storage Studio ... Right ?

Comment: When you lock a message, you make it invisible to all parties which do not possess the key. Only by releasing the lock or having the lock expire can another client see the message.

This is why you should take out locks with short leases (less-than 5 minutes) and renew them if you are processing for longer periods of time. A lease of 72 hours is asking for problems.